# R predictor variables in code not processing the correct answer

Tags: r

I'm not too sure why this chunk of code isn't working; assistance would be appreciated!

I have tried everything and have ensured that IsHappy is a factor so I'm not too sure why it isn't working.

```
happy = read.csv("happy.csv")
library(klaR)

happy$A1 = as.factor(happy$A1)
happy$A3 = as.factor(happy$A3)
happy$IsHappy = as.factor(happy$IsHappy)
happy.nb =NaiveBayes(IsHappy~A1+A3, data = happy)


happy.prediction = predict(happy.nb)
table(Actual = happy$IsHappy, Predicted = happy.prediction)
```

all arguments must have the same length

Comment: Is this copy-and-pasted? You've got `happy.prediction` and `happy.predictions`, which are two different variables in there.

Comment: And if that's not the problem, try `head(happy.prediction)` to see the shape of the data. It might be something more complex than a vector of factors (not familiar with `klaR`).

Comment: Oops! That was a typo - but not the problem. I'll try that now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Literally spent days on this and this was the fix:

```
table(Actual = spamdata2$IsHappy, Predicted = happy.prediction$class)
```

@Jason: that was a typo when posting the question, all fixed now.